# Destroying a publisher using node.destroy_publisher raises Invalid Handle exception

Tags: ros2, publisher, node

I'm trying to trigger a camera which is configured to use trigger mode in ROS2 Humble, Gazebo. I create a publisher inside a state in our state machine, to publish the trigger topic. Once the state caputures an image and info topic publish event, I wish to stop triggering and destroy the publisher, so that each time the state runs it does not create new publishers.

I am having trouble with the call to `self.node.destroy_publisher(trigger_pub)`, which sometimes raises an exception (not always).

Note I attempt to destroy the timer before destroying the publisher, so it should not trigger the timer again needing the publisher handle.

Any ideas? How do I elegantly destroy a publisher?

**Using ROS2 Humble.**

**Exception:**

```
[xxxxxx.py-10]     arg = take_from_wait_list(entity)
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 335, in _take_subscription
[xxxxxx.py-10]     with sub.handle:
[xxxxxx.py-10] rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.InvalidHandle: cannot use Destroyable because destruction was requested
```

**Another, similar:**

```
xxxxxx.py-10] [INFO 1692860552.248581973] [CaptureImage]: Triggering camera: /front_cameras_cover_camera_right (trigger_timer_cb() at capture_image.py:73)
[xxxxxx.py-10]     self.spin_once()
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 764, in spin_once
[xxxxxx.py-10]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 745, in _spin_once_impl
[xxxxxx.py-10]     handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 691, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
[xxxxxx.py-10]     return next(self._cb_iter)
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 585, in _wait_for_ready_callbacks
[xxxxxx.py-10]     waitable.add_to_wait_set(wait_set)
[xxxxxx.py-10]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos_event.py", line 114, in add_to_wait_set
[xxxxxx.py-10]     with self.__event:
[xxxxxx.py-10] rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.InvalidHandle: cannot use Destroyable because destruction was requested
```

**Relevant code:**

````py
trigger_pub = self.node.create_publisher(
                Empty,
                '{}/image_trigger'.format(camera_namespace),
                qos_profile=default_qos)

            def trigger_timer_cb():
                try:
                    self.logger.info('Triggering camera: {}'.format(camera_namespace))
                    trigger_pub.publish(Empty())
                except BaseException:
                    self.logger.warn('Captured exception {}'.format(camera_namespace))
                    pass

            trigger_timer = self.node.create_timer(1, trigger_timer_cb, self.__timer_cb_group)

            # Start listening for images
            start_time = self.node.get_clock().now()
            timeout = Duration(seconds=30.0)

            success = False
            rate = self.node.create_rate(10)
            while rclpy.ok() and self.node.get_clock().now() < (start_time + timeout):
                rate.sleep()
                success = self._info_captured and self._image_captured
                if success:
                    break

            if not self.node.destroy_rate(rate):
                self.logger.warning('Failed to destroy rate in capture image skill')

            if not self.node.destroy_subscription(image_sub):
                self.logger.warning('Subscriber for topic {} was not correctly destroyed'.format(image_sub.topic_name))

            if not self.node.destroy_subscription(info_sub):
                self.logger.warning('Subscriber for topic {} was not correctly destroyed'.format(info_sub.topic_name))

            if not self.node.destroy_timer(trigger_timer):
                self.logger.warning('Timer for publisher {} not correctly destroyed'.format(camera_namespace))
            else:
                if not self.node.destroy_publisher(trigger_pub):
                    self.logger.warning('Error while destroying publisher {}'.format(camera_namespace))
```
````